# convert lambda function to regular function PYTHON df["domain_count"] = df.apply(lambda row : df['domain'].value_counts()[row['domain']], axis = 1)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this current lambda function: `df["domain_count"] = df.apply(lambda row : df['domain'].value_counts()[row['domain']], axis = 1)`

But I want to convert it to a regular function like this `def get_domain_count()` how do I do this? I'm not sure what parameters it would take in as I want to apply it to an entire column in a dataframe? The `domain` column will contain duplicates and I want to know how many times a domain appears in my dataframe.

```
ex start df:

|domain|
---
|target.com|
|macys.com|
|target.com|
|walmart.com|
|walmart.com|
|target.com|

ex end df:
|domain|count|
---|---|
|target.com|3
|macys.com|1
|target.com|3
|walmart.com|2
|walmart.com|2
|target.com|3
```

Please help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: This `lambda` has a single parameter `row` if that helps

Comment: The challenge here is how the `df` variable will be resolved. Do you still want to use the function in a `DataFrame.apply` operation?

Comment: @tdelaney it doesn't need to be a `dataframe.apply` operation i think? i'm not really sure my end goal is to use it to create a new column in the dataframe that has the counts based on the domain name in a diff column

Comment: @codingrainha - I think I covered the apply case in my answer. My answer changed the call signature, but that means it can't be used in .apply without some other work done. BTW, I think that lambda is problematic as it recalculates `value_counts` on each row. You could move it out of the .apply using the partials trick I did in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the column name as a string, and the dataframe object to mutate:

```py
def countify(frame, col_name):
    frame[f"{col_name}_count"] = frame.apply(lambda row: df[col_name]...)
```

But better yet, you don't need to apply!

```py
df["domain"].map(df["domain"].value_counts())
```

will first get the counts per unique value, and map each value in the column with that. So the function could become:

```py
def countify(frame, col_name):
    frame[f"{col_name}_count"] = frame[col_name].map(frame[col_name].value_counts())
```

Comment: I interpreted the question differently, but I like your answer. I'm just commenting to note that you do the entire apply operation on the dataframe while I just return the calculated value.

Comment: thanks reason for making it mutative is due to new column's name depending on the incoming column's name, i.e., suffixed "_count".

Answer (score 1):

A lambda is just an anonymous function and its usually easy to put it into a function using the lambda's own parameter list (in this case, `row`) and returning its expression. The challenge with this one is the `df` parameter that will resolve differently in a module level function than in your lambda. So, add that as a parameter to the function. The problem is that this will not be

```
def get_domain_count(df, row): 
    return df['domain'].value_counts()[row['domain']]
```

This can be a problem if you still want to use this function in an `.apply` operation. `.apply` wouldn't know to add that `df` parameter at the front. To solve that, you could create a partial.

```
import functools.partial

def do_stuff(some_df):
    some_df.apply(functools.partial(get_domain_count, some_df))
```

Comment: how would i implement this? what would i pass in as the `row` parameter? apologies as this is new to me.

would it be something like this: `df["domain_count] = get_domain_count(df, "domain")`?

Comment: @codingrainha -  .apply applies the function to each row. For row 0 for instance, it would be more like `df.iloc[0, "domain_count_0"] = get_domain_count(df, df.iloc[0])`. In my answer I am just turning the lambda into a function and the lambda only returns a value for a single row.